# Dynamically include function on markup in angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Creating a new element directive in angularjs.  In the HTML markup for the partial template, I need to dynamically specify a function for the `ng-click` attribute. I have tried several ways to accomplish this, but I receive a `$parse.syntax` error on all of them.

I've included code of latest attempt in the hope that someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Directive module:

```
(function(){

angular.module('scheduleDirective', [])

.directive('schedule', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      person: '=',
          day: '=',
    },
    templateUrl: 'schedulepartial.html',
    controller: function($scope, $element,$attrs,$http){

        this.callToggle = "schedule.toggle(person, '" + $attrs.day + "')";
        this.setClass = '{' + "'active' : person[" + $attrs.day + "], 'btn-primary' : person[" + $attrs.day + '] }';

        this.toggle = function(person,day){         
              console.log("toggle" + person.name + day);  
            .
            .
            .
        s},
    controllerAs: 'scheduleDirCtrl'
  };
});
```

Directive partial:

```
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline btn-sm"  ng-click= {{scheduleDirCtrl.callToggle}}  
        ng-class={{scheduleDirCtrl.setClass}}>{{day}}</a>
```

UPDATE based on answer below:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline btn-sm"  ng-click=scheduleDirCtrl.callToggle()  
            ng-class={{scheduleDirCtrl.setClass}}>{{day}}</a>
```

HTML Markup for index page:

```
<schedule person = person day="july25">July 25</schedule>
```

Oddly enough, the `ng-class` attribute works fine, but the same pattern in the `ng-click` attribute produces the `$parse.syntax` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$parse.syntax` error is occurring because `scheduleDirCtrl.callToggle` is not of type function. Just do something like this for `callToggle`:

```
this.callToggle = function() {
    this.schedule.toggle(person, $attrs.day);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked perfectly!  I just had to change the directive html markup to call the function correctly.  I removed the eval operator {{ }} and added parentheses.  I've added an update to the original post to show the correct syntax.